# How To Change A Filter Input Through A Separate Button

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a list that can be filtered through standard filter inputs and by selecting a link. For example, you can filter the county "Butler" by changing the filter input or by selecting the link "Butler County" above the table. The standard filters work great but I cannot get the link above to change the filter input below. I need to do this to over 3,000 counties and the link needs to change the filter option below so the user knows which county is filtered, any help would be highly appreciated!

```
        <a href="#" class="county">Butler County</a>

<div class="row">

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr class="filters">
            <th>County <!--User-->
            <select id="assigned-county-filter" class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>Sedgwick</option>
                <option>Butler</option>
                <option>Harvey</option>
            </select>
            </th>
            <th>City <!--Status-->
            <select id="city-filter" class="form-control">
                <option>Any</option>
                <option>Wichita</option>
                <option>Newton</option>
                <option>Andover</option>
                <option>El Dorado</option>
                <option>Pratt</option>
            </select>
            </th>
            <th>Parking Type <!--Milestone-->
            <select id="type-filter" class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>RV Park</option>
                <option>Tiny House Community</option>
            </select>
            </th>
            <th>THA Verified? <!--Priority-->
            <select id="verification-filter" class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
            </th>
            <th>Tags
            <select id="tags-filter" class="form-control">
                <option>All</option>
                <option>50+</option>
                <option>Homestead</option>
            </select>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="task-5" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="5" data-assigned-county="Sedgwick" data-city="Wichita" data-type="Tiny House Community" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="None">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h3 class="listing-title">Bubba's Tiny House Community</h3>
                        <p class="listing-description">
                            2372 Village Road<br>
                            Wichita, Kansas 31162<br>
                            +1.735.421.5435
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
        <div id="task-4" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="4" data-assigned-county="Butler" data-city="El Dorado" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="None">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h3 class="listing-title">Corner Stone RV Park</h3>
                        <p class="listing-description">
                            2372 Corner Stone Drive<br>
                            El Dorado, Kansas 31162<br>
                            +1.735.421.5435
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
        <div id="task-3" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="3" data-assigned-county="Pratt" data-city="Pratt" data-type="Tiny House Community" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="Homestead">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h3 class="listing-title">Lakeside Village</h3>
                        <p class="listing-description">
                            2372 Lakeside Drive<br>
                            Pratt, Kansas 31162<br>
                            +1.735.421.5435
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div> 


    <div class="row">
        <div id="task-2" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="2" data-assigned-county="Harvey" data-city="Newton" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="No" data-tags="50+">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h3 class="listing-title">Sunset RV Park</h3>
                        <p class="listing-description">
                            2372 Allendale Drive<br>
                            Newton, Kansas 31162<br>
                            +1.735.421.5435
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <h3 class="verification">Not Verified | Verifiy Now</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="row">
        <div id="task-1" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="1" data-assigned-county="Butler" data-city="Andover" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="No" data-tags="None">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h3 class="listing-title">Trojan RV Park</h3>
                        <p class="listing-description">
                            2372 1st Drive<br>
                            Andover, Kansas 31162<br>
                            +1.735.421.5435
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg">
                        <h3 class="verification">Not Verified | Verify Now</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div> 

</section>
```

Hope this link works! [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mharvey/fe0jLqzu/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a onclick event to the button. This is a possible solution

```js
var
  userFilter, statusFilter, milestoneFilter, priorityFilter, tagsFilter;

function updateFilters() {
  $('.task-list-row').hide().filter(function() {
    var
      self = $(this),
      result = true; // not guilty until proven guilty

    if (userFilter && (userFilter != 'All')) {
      result = result && userFilter === self.data('assigned-county');
    }
    if (statusFilter && (statusFilter != 'Any')) {
      result = result && statusFilter === self.data('city');
    }
    if (milestoneFilter && (milestoneFilter != 'All')) {
      result = result && milestoneFilter === self.data('type');
    }
    if (priorityFilter && (priorityFilter != 'All')) {
      result = result && priorityFilter === self.data('verification');
    }
    if (tagsFilter && (tagsFilter != 'All')) {
      result = result && tagsFilter === self.data('tags');
    }

    return result;
  }).show();
}

// Assigned County Dropdown Filter
$('#assigned-county-filter').on('change', function() {
  userFilter = this.value;
  updateFilters();
});

// Task City Dropdown Filter
$('#city-filter').on('change', function() {
  statusFilter = this.value;
  updateFilters();
});

// Task Parking Type Dropdown Filter
$('#type-filter').on('change', function() {
  milestoneFilter = this.value;
  updateFilters();
});

// Task Verification Dropdown Filter
$('#verification-filter').on('change', function() {
  priorityFilter = this.value;
  updateFilters();
});

// Task Tags Dropdown Filter
$('#tags-filter').on('change', function() {
  tagsFilter = this.value;
  updateFilters();
});

//Added in a click function
$('#bc').click(function() {
  $('#assigned-county-filter').val('Butler').trigger('change');
})
```

```css
.listing {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px #737373 solid;
}

.listing-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.listing-description {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
}

.verification {
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container" style="margin-top:10rem;">

  <!--An id here to reference in js-->
  <a href="#" id="bc" class="county">Butler County</a>

  <div class="row">

    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr class="filters">
          <th>County
            <!--User-->
            <select id="assigned-county-filter" class="form-control">
              <option>All</option>
              <option>Sedgwick</option>
              <option>Butler</option>
              <option>Harvey</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th>City
            <!--Status-->
            <select id="city-filter" class="form-control">
              <option>Any</option>
              <option>Wichita</option>
              <option>Newton</option>
              <option>Andover</option>
              <option>El Dorado</option>
              <option>Pratt</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th>Parking Type
            <!--Milestone-->
            <select id="type-filter" class="form-control">
              <option>All</option>
              <option>RV Park</option>
              <option>Tiny House Community</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th>THA Verified?
            <!--Priority-->
            <select id="verification-filter" class="form-control">
              <option>All</option>
              <option>Yes</option>
              <option>No</option>
            </select>
          </th>
          <th>Tags
            <select id="tags-filter" class="form-control">
              <option>All</option>
              <option>50+</option>
              <option>Homestead</option>
            </select>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="task-5" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="5" data-assigned-county="Sedgwick" data-city="Wichita" data-type="Tiny House Community" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="None">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="listing-title">Bubba's Tiny House Community</h3>
              <p class="listing-description">
                2372 Village Road<br> Wichita, Kansas 31162<br> +1.735.421.5435
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div id="task-4" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="4" data-assigned-county="Butler" data-city="El Dorado" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="None">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="listing-title">Corner Stone RV Park</h3>
              <p class="listing-description">
                2372 Corner Stone Drive<br> El Dorado, Kansas 31162<br> +1.735.421.5435
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div id="task-3" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="3" data-assigned-county="Pratt" data-city="Pratt" data-type="Tiny House Community" data-verification="Yes" data-tags="Homestead">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="listing-title">Lakeside Village</h3>
              <p class="listing-description">
                2372 Lakeside Drive<br> Pratt, Kansas 31162<br> +1.735.421.5435
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h3 class="verification">THA Verified</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div id="task-2" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="2" data-assigned-county="Harvey" data-city="Newton" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="No" data-tags="50+">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="listing-title">Sunset RV Park</h3>
              <p class="listing-description">
                2372 Allendale Drive<br> Newton, Kansas 31162<br> +1.735.421.5435
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h3 class="verification">Not Verified | Verifiy Now</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="task-1" class="task-list-row listing" data-task-id="1" data-assigned-county="Butler" data-city="Andover" data-type="RV Park" data-verification="No" data-tags="None">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h3 class="listing-title">Trojan RV Park</h3>
              <p class="listing-description">
                2372 1st Drive<br> Andover, Kansas 31162<br> +1.735.421.5435
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg">
              <h3 class="verification">Not Verified | Verify Now</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</section>
```